# Is integrating Topaz Signature Pads into a web-based ticketing system with a Chrome Extension viable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The IT Support Center that I work at uses a ticketing system that has a browser-based front end. Currently when create a ticket, we print them out with the terms and conditions and have the custom sign physically with paper and pencil. Our goal is to move to a paperless system where the customer uses a Topaz Signature pad (That we already have) to sign the tickets to agree to the terms.

So my question is, is it a viable option to use the JS [SigWeb API](http://www.topazsystems.com/sigweb.html) in a Chrome Extension to do this?

Currently our ticketing software has a "Sign" function where when clicked, it pops up a field where you can sign with a mouse or tablet touch screen with finger. After signing, you can press the sign button and an PNG is attached to the ticket. Do you think that I could possibly execute a JS script (provided by the WebSig API) after the field for signing pops up that allows me to use the signature pad for input rather than a mouse or tablet touchscreen. Also, if you guys have any insight on how I would go about doing this with a Chrome Extension (As I'm quite new at Extension Development), I would be glad to take any pointers and directions from you.

If you need clarification for anything above, let me know.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: A few questions, 1. what type is your ticketing software? Is it a web page or a desktop application? 2. When you are saying 'use the signature pad', how will the `use the signature pad` api be called? by web page, desktop application or chrome extension?

Comment: @HaibaraAi, the ticketing system is called iSupport - support.com | If you visit the link provided above "SigWeb API" there is a download. I downloaded and installed it. TBH, I'm not sure what I installed but I assumer it's a driver. It allows you to use the SigWeb API with chrome. I tested it with some of Topaz Demos and it works in chrome after installing that driver. So when using the demos, you just navigate to a certain web url so I assume that there is some sort of server or listener driver that gets called although I'm not sure. Any other questions I can answer to clear things up?

Comment: Sorry I still didn't catch that... In general if you could use SigWeb API in normal page, then you could also do that with chrome extension, since content script just runs in the web page.